# Compare X co-ordinates of mouse click with current position of div (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, velocity.js

I'm not use to Javascript however with previous programming experience I'm just a little lost as to why the else statement is always called in the following:

```
function moveDiv(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var $div = $("div");  // Used for velocity called in head of html
  var currentPos = document.getElementById("div").style.left; // parse current position in div (set inline)

  if (currentPos > x) {
    $div.velocity({rotateZ:0, left:x+"px"},2000, "ease-in-out");
    alert("CurrentPos is greater than x");
  } 
  else {
    $div.velocity({rotateZ:0, left:x+"px"},100, "ease-in-out");  // Always called
  }
}
```

Comment: You are assigning the variable $div to all the div-tags. And then you are assigning the currentPos on an element with the id of "div". Is this really what you meant to do?

Comment: `currentPos ` is not a number

Comment: Further @charlietfl `currentPos` will return `15px` (for example) but not `15`. It will return `15px` only if this style is inline style like: `<div style="left:15px"></div>` otherwise it will return an empty string (`''`) See this [bin](http://jsbin.com/lamago/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: What a muppet seems obvious now, thanks guys.